# Do Processes take up memory after it has finished running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am write an operational script which starts processes at specific times of the day. The script will be running constantly, as such I am afraid that the creation and starting of processes will take up memory.

I write a short script to see what happens to the Process after it has finished running the function.

```
# t.py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(t=0):
    time.sleep(t)

a = mp.Process(target=f, args=(10, ))
a.start()
print(a.pid)

time.sleep(10000)
```

---

```
$ python3 t.py
32263
```

I then run the following to see what processes are running

```
$ ps auxf | grep python t.py
user   32262  3.0  0.1  21360 11200 pts/0    S+   11:37   0:00      |   \_ python3 t.py
user   32263  0.0  0.0  21360  7704 pts/0    S+   11:37   0:00      |       \_ python3 t.py
```

This shows that `a` is still present despite having finished running. I found that the `pid 32263` only disappears if i include `a.join()` in the script. But this would block me from starting and creating other processes.

Is there any way to kill `a` for good? `a.kill()` and `a.terminate()` does not seem to do the job.

If I were to neglect the fact that `a` still appears in `ps auxf`, and I were to keep on creating and starting new processes, would that take up memory?

Comment: The process should exit after waiting for 10 seconds. Did you run the `ps` command 10 seconds after running the script?

Comment: @scene_contra yes I did, not setting`args` will give the same result

Comment: Ran the script, works as expected for me. The child process exits after sleep.

Comment: @scene_contra, so you are saying that you cannot see it in `ps auxf`?

Comment: Yeah, only the parent process is running after 10 seconds.